# Type metadata accessor for DeepLabV3Output XCode 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode13, deeplab, mlmodel

After building with XCode 13 when app try to predict Image using DeepLabV3's processing APP crash.

The same code with Xcode 12 work correctly

Someone can help me?
thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQTQp.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem printing error in the debug *symbol stub for: type metadata accessor for CoreML.MLShapedArray* in the below part of the generated code

```swift
func prediction(input: DeepLabV3Input, options: MLPredictionOptions) throws -> DeepLabV3Output { 
let outFeatures = try model.prediction(from: input, options:options) 
return DeepLabV3Output(features: outFeatures) }  // -> ERROR is happening here
```

Comment: How to solve this error?